# No Json serializer found when trying to compose JsObject

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

my json is a `JsValu`

```
// this is a list of JsObject extracted from a json
val parents = (json \ "parents").as[List[JsObject]]

// a map between parent name to list of their kids
val kidsNamesMap = (json \ "kids").as[Map[String,List[String]]]

// creating a new JsObject
 val newParent = parent + ("kids" -> Json.toJson(kidsNamesMap.getOrElse(parentName,"")))
```

when compiling i get an error:

> No Json serializer found for type Object. Try to implement an implicit
>   Writes or Format for this type.
>            val newParent = parent + ("kids" -> Json.toJson(kidsNamesMap.getOrElse(parentName,"")))

but im now sure what writer to add, wrote writer before for my case class but here im not sure...

thanks

Comment: Thats because `kidsNamesMap.getOrElse(parentName,"")` will not really have a type. From the map you either get a List[String] or you get a string (.getOrElse). The ideal way would be to replace this as: ```val newParent = parent + ("kids" -> {
  kidsNamesMap.get(parentName).map(Json.toJson(_)).getOrElse(JsString(""))
})```

Comment: please add it as answer :)

Comment: @JohnBiggs done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `kidsNamesMap.getOrElse(parentName,"")` will not really have a type. From the map you either get a `List[String]` or you get a `String` (`.getOrElse`). 
The ideal way would be to replace this as:

```
val newParent = parent + ( "kids" -> { kidsNamesMap.get(parentName).map(Json.toJson(_)).getOrElse(J‌​sString("")) } )
```